# Replace New Attribute's Value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

My input is a string like:`<Identification LastName="Bornery" Name="John" Age="23"/>` and I want to convert it to Xml and then change it like:`<Identification LastName="Bornery" Name="John" Age="40"/>`

Comment: In some cases I have to work with strings that originated from Xml format and I must try to convert these tow formats to each other an do some changes on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, but lots of other ways as well. What's best for you will require more information.

```
var xd = XDocument.Parse(@"<Identification LastName=""Bornery"" Name=""John"" Age=""23""/>");
xd.Element("Identification").Attribute("Age").Value = "40";
string result = xd.ToString();
```